# pg_restore using improper database name

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I want copy a 'local' postgres database, which living in docker, into remote machine. Local docker's databse have default name `postgres`, and remote have `proddb`. I run following command:

```bash
pg_dump --format=custom --dbname=postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres | PGPASSWORD=pa$$word pg_restore -v --clean --create --host=production.local --username=swasher --dbname=proddb
```

In the terminal, i see that this command creating `postgres` database instead `proddb`:

```bash
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: dropping DATABASE postgres
pg_restore: creating DATABASE "postgres"
pg_restore: connecting to new database "postgres"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "DATABASE postgres"
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION "hstore"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "EXTENSION hstore"
pg_restore: terminated by user
```

Why pg_restore ignored specified `dbname` key?

Comment: pg_dump makes a backup of the postgres database and you put --clean --create in this dump. When you give this dump to pg_restore, it will just do what you told it to do. The connection used by pg_restore is just the initial connection, the one used for dropping the postgres database and creating a new one.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Exactly as you say, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `--create` option with `pg_restore`, the restore process will first execute

```
CREATE DATABASE postgres;
```

then connect to the new database with

```
\c postgres
```

and proceed to restore the dump.

If you additionally add `--clean`, `pg_restore` will first execute

```
DROP DATABASE postgres;
```

So the database you connect to with `pg_restore` is irrelevant, because `pg_restore` will create and connect to database `postgres` anyway.

If you want to restore the dump to a different database, omit the `--create` option, so that `pg_restore` connects to `proddb` and restores the dump to that database.